# Who do you call a person who do paperwork for a university's program?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what should we call a student who doing all the paperwork and all stuff regarding formal letter for a program in a university 's club organization? is it program secretary?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps. It looks like shouting. Also, if you could add more details, I think that might be helpful. Is the student paid? What kind of club is it? An example sentence or dialogue, etc. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: Is [this the kind of info](http://www.clubsolutions.wales/committee-roles/) you're after? (note it's only a guideline)